# get_called_class ou de new static?

Tags: php, classes

Eu não lembro qual foi a biblioteca em PHP que vi isso, mas lá existia um trecho de código onde, para se obter uma nova instância da classe atual, era usado a função `get_called_class`.

Porém o PHP tem a palavra chave `static`, que se refere ao late static binding.

Parece que o uso dos dois produz o mesmo resultado.

Veja:

```
class Yea
{
    public static function withStatic()
    {
        return new static;
    }

    public static function withCalledClass()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();
        return new $class;
    }
}


var_dump(Yea::withStatic());
var_dump(Yea::withCalledClass());
```

Já que a saída é a mesma, por que alguns preferem usar `get_called_class`, ao invés do `static`?

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/Aw5tSU)

Comment: Seria pelo fato de `get_called_class` estar disponível do php5.3 para frente? testa esse código no https://3v4l.org/ ele vai rodar em várias versões do php. +1

Comment: PHP 5.3 funfou https://3v4l.org/rmmvc

Comment: E no 5.2 pra baixo? deu erro ou deu outro resultado? não tenho acesso ...

Comment: Não mostrou nenhum resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vale ressaltar que a função `get_called_class` veio a existir a partir da versão **5.3** do PHP.

Além da diferença de performances como citadas pelo Rafael

> ```
> class Foo {
>     public static function bar()
>     {
>         echo "\n get_called_class: ";
>         $time = microtime(true);
>         echo get_called_class(). ' ';
>         printf('%f', microtime(true) - $time);
>
>         echo "\n static: ";
>         $time = microtime(true);
>         echo static::class . ' ';
>         printf('%f', microtime(true) - $time);
>     }
> }
>
> echo "<pre>";
> Foo::bar();
> ```
>
> Resultado:
>
> ```
> get_called_class: Bar 0.000006
>
> static: Bar 0.000001
> ```

Existe uma outra questão que deve ser levantada.
O `get_called_class` é usado em parceria com o `late static binding` em frameworks.
Por exemplo, quando um framework busca utilizar um sistema de service locator/IoC, costumam utilizar o `get_called_class`, pois como essa função retorna o nome da classe e isso pode ser utilizado para verificar se já existem instâncias juntos com a utilização do **FactoryPattern**

Exemplo

```
class Factory
{
    private static $_instances = array();

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();
        if (!isset(self::$_instances[$class])) {
            self::$_instances[$class] = new $class();
        }
        return self::$_instances[$class];
    }
}

class ClassExtendFactory extends Factory {}

$class = ClassExtendFactory::getInstance();
$otherClass = ClassExtendFactory::getInstance();
var_dump($class === $otherClass);
// result true { ou seja, representam o mesmo objeto, duas variáveis apontando para o mesmo endereço de alocamento da memória }
```

Quando não utilizam a factory, somente usam o `late static binding`

```
abstract class AbstractExample {
    public static function getInstance() {
        return new static();
    }
}

class Example extends AbstractExample {

}

$ex1 = Example::getInstance();
$ex2 = Example::getInstance();
var_dump($ex1 === $ex2);
// return false { ou seja, agora são 2 instâncias diferentes da mesma class, duas variáveis apontando para espaços diferentes de alocamento na memória }
```

É isso, espero que tenha ajudado a entender um pouco melhor.

Answer (score 5):

A função `get_called_class()` retorna o **nome** da classe, enquanto `static` retorna a própria classe.

A partir do PHP 5.5, você também pode usar `static::class` para retornar o nome da classe.

Acredito que seja mais uma questão de estilo, mas eu recomendaria usar o `static` (principalmente se o seu objetivo é instanciar a classe, como no seu exemplo), por duas razões:

- 1)  É mais Curto, seu código fica mais limpo;
- 2)  Performance. Apesar de quase imperceptível, qualquer chamada de função tem custos.

Você pode fazer uma comparação simples, assim:

```
class Foo {
    public static function bar()
    {
        echo "\n get_called_class: ";
        $time = microtime(true);
        echo get_called_class(). ' ';
        printf('%f', microtime(true) - $time);

        echo "\n static: ";
        $time = microtime(true);
        echo static::class . ' ';
        printf('%f', microtime(true) - $time);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
Foo::bar();
```

Resultado:

> get_called_class: Bar 0.000006
>
> static: Bar 0.000001

Esses tempos podem variar um pouco em cada page load.

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta. Mas sabe se a questão da versão pode influenciar na hora de um framework utilizar `get_called_class` ou `static`?

Comment: Os frameworks costumam definir uma versão mínima. Geralmente essa informação fica logo na primeira página da documentação, ou na seção "Instalação". Resumindo, a versão influencia sim. Se você estiver desenvolvendo um Framework seu, então tem que escolher se quer dar suporte apenas às versões mais modernas, ou manter compatibilidade com as versões anteriores.

Comment: Sempre determino PHP 5.4 ++

Comment: Provavelmente, essa lib que vc viu queria pegar o nome da classe em versões anteriores à 5.5. Existem outras opções para fazer isso também, como a variável `__CLASS__` ou `get_class($this)` (se o método não for estático)